# Update all columns in one row (adding xxx-xxx to beginning of every row)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to update the column `UserID` by adding `DOMAIN-NAME\` to every user in all rows. I saw how to remove all in one row

```
UPDATE Employee
SET EMP_Name = REPLACE(Emp_name, 'xx\', '')
```

But how do I do it in reverse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa655/2)**

```
UPDATE Employee
SET UserID  = 'DOMAIN-NAME\' + UserID
```

Result:

```
| ID |    TYPE |                          USERID |
--------------------------------------------------
|  1 |   Email | DOMAIN-NAME\admin@sqlfiddle.com |
|  2 | Twitter |          DOMAIN-NAME\@sqlfiddle |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Employee
SET EMP_Name = 'xx\' + Emp_name
```

Comment: Actually, with ms sql, the concat operator is a plus sign.  Care to edit your answer?